# How to write a Java interface whose implementation would potentially be asynchronous?

Tags: java, asynchronous, methods, repository, remote-access

### What I need

I have a contract (interface) that describes an `UserRepository`. I want this repository to have a method allowing to *get* an `User` from his/her email, throwing a *checked* exception if no `User` with the given email was found. The interface would then look just like this:

```java
interface UserRepository {

    User get(String email) throws UserNotFoundException;

}
```

### Possible implementations

Now let's consider 2 implementations of this contract. One which would use an **in-memory** store (1) and another which would use a **remote** store (2).

1. Regarding the **in-memory** store, the implemented operation would be blocking while fast enough not to worry about performance.
2. However, if I where to implement this operation on a **remote** store (e.g. a remote database), I would then have to take the performance/speed in consideration, as I would not get the response immediately. The solution to avoid blocking the current thread while waiting for the response to arrive is to use some asynchronous handling.

### The issue

Obviously, my current contract is not designed to handle this operation in an asynchronous fashion.

Now, do I have to change my contract (interface) knowing that some implementations would *potentially* need an async handling of some sort? In other words, do I make this operation async by contract even though some implementations might not even need to execute the code asynchronously in another thread?

### The options

Here are 2 options I have considered:

```java
interface UserRepository {

    /**
     * 1st option.
     * Maybe specify in the javadoc that some implementations might block the current thread.
     */
    User get(String email) throws UserNotFoundException;

    /**
     * 2nd option.
     * Method "async" by contract and lost of checked exceptions.
     */
    CompletableFuture<User> get(String email);

}
```

I don't really know what's the best option here. I could potentially use some Observer/Listener pattern here but I think it's overkill for such a small operation.

What do you think? Is there a conventional and conceptual approach for solving this kind of problems? Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is decomposed incorrectly.  If the caller of `get()` isn't going to complete and won't block, they need to be aware that the operation might not complete.  So you can't return a `User` there.  Look at supplying an asynchronous callback for when that operation does complete.

Comment: How long do you assume accessing the remote database will take?

Comment: @markspace Couldn't I still return an `User` even if I throw an exception in case of timeout or request failed (talking abount the signature of the method here)?

Comment: @Kayaman How would that matter? I mean, what if the request fails or times out? In that case, it would take too much time for the operation to be blocking.

Comment: How would you wait for the exception to be thrown if you're not going to block?  There's no way to do this if you don't block.  If you find a timeout, then you've blocked while waiting for the timeout.  I don't see any other way.

Comment: You might be thinking Java acts like Javascript which has a different threading model. It doesn't really matter if the thread blocks waiting for results (whatever they may be), if you need it to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your Question, but I suspect needing to make your repository interface aware of asynchronous implementations is unnecessary (and likely a poor design choice).

Instead of returning a `User` and throwing a special exception if not found, I suggest using [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) as your return value from your interface method. The `Optional` class is meant to wrap an object reference that may legitimately be null, as opposed to null indicating an error. In the [Generics syntax of Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), we say `Optional < User >` which means an `Optional` wrapper that either carries a `User` object specifically or carries nothing at all.

So let’s change that interface to look like this.

```java
package work.basil.demo.wait;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository
{
    Optional < User > fetchByEmail ( String email );
}
```

Here is an implementation of that interface that returns a fake object.

We make a `User` object using whatever email arrives as the argument. To that email address, we attach a user name value of `Fake`. These values are put in our `User` object.

We sleep a moment in the `fetchByEmail` method to simulate a fetch to a database that takes a while.

At the bottom, we have two endings. One line returns a fake user. The other returns an empty `Optional` to simulate not finding a match. You can comment in/out either line to toggle behaviors.

```java
package work.basil.demo.wait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

public class FakeUserRepository implements UserRepository
{
    @Override
    public Optional < User > fetchByEmail ( String email )
    {
        // Validate inputs.
        Objects.requireNonNull( email , "Email argument must be provided, cannot be null. Message # a6d23f55-8ac9-490b-9969-b444d3db0737." );
        if ( email.isBlank() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Email argument cannot be blank. Message # 793f58f5-c7be-4ebb-9351-0319809a6971." ); }

        // Sleep a moment to pretend that this method takes a while to hit the database before returning.
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 2 ).toMillis() ); }catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        // Return whatever email is sent, inventing fake `User` object.
        return Optional.of( new User( email , "Fake" ) );

        // Return empty optional, to simulate the case where the desired email address is not found to belong to any existing users.
//        return Optional.empty() ;
    }
}
```

Here is our simple `User` class. We use the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature of Java 16 for brevity. You could just as well define a conventional class.

```java
public record User(String email , String name) {}
```

Finally, our app class with a `main` method to demo this in action.

First we establish our repository object. This could be done much earlier in the lifecycle of your real app.

We establish an executor service to handle our background threading. To that service we submit an instance of our task, a call to the repository’s `fetchByEmail` method. Here we use lambda syntax, but you could just as well use conventional syntax. Notice that after `submit` we call `shutdown` on our service. This stops any more submissions, and asks the service to shut down after the already-submitted tasks are done. This call does *not* block.

We go on to do other work in the mean while, other work that need not wait for the `User` object. In this code, we simulate the other work by sleeping the current thread.

Eventually we have completed all the work we can do without our `User` object. So we call `get` on the `Future` object. **This call blocks.** The current thread waits for the background thread to finish and return our needed `User` object. If the background thread has already finished, this `get` method returns immediately.

After unwrapping the `Optional`, we have a `User` object in hand. Or we found the `Optional` to be empty, in which case we know that no match was found for that email address input value (or something went wrong during the query).

```java
package work.basil.demo.wait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        UserRepository userRepository = new FakeUserRepository();
        // …
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Callable < Optional < User > > task = ( ) -> userRepository.fetchByEmail( "fake@example.com" );
        Future < Optional < User > > future = executorService.submit( task );
        executorService.shutdown();  // Shuts down the executor service after previously submitted tasks are done/cancelled/failed.

        // Do some  stuff.
        // We sleep this thread to pretend that some other work is executing.
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 3 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        // Other work done. So now we need our `User` object from repository before we can proceed.
        if ( future.isCancelled() )
        {
            // Deal with task being cancelled.
        } else
        {
            Optional < User > optionalUser = null; // Blocks, waiting until done to return result. Or, if already done, immediately returns result.
            try { optionalUser = future.get(); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }catch ( ExecutionException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            if ( optionalUser.isPresent() )
            {
                System.out.println( "user = " + optionalUser.get() + ". Message # 2bff0033-3000-4b77-b8e0-654cf51db88b." );
            } else // Else no user found, the Optional is empty.
            {
                System.out.println( "No user found. The Optional is empty. Message # cd733ffe-0a38-4813-9c80-98f5d9c35755." );
            }
        }

        if ( Objects.nonNull( executorService ) )
        {
            try { executorService.awaitTermination( 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        System.out.println( "Demo done. Message # e64cc194-2087-4aae-a142-3a27a4950483." );
    }
}
```

When run, we get output like this.

> user = User[email=fake@example.com, name=Fake]. Message # 2bff0033-3000-4b77-b8e0-654cf51db88b.
>
> Demo done. Message # e64cc194-2087-4aae-a142-3a27a4950483.